# Function using input() for default parameters -- inputs collected but no output printed

Tags: python

I tried making a program to get inputs for the variables in a quadratic equation and print the roots.

```
import math

def quadratic_solver(a = input("Enter the value of a "), b = input("Enter the value of b "), c = input("Enter the value of c ")):
    dis = b * b - 4 * a * c 
    sqrt_val = math.sqrt(abs(dis)) 
   
    if dis > 0: 
        print((-b + sqrt_val)/(2 * a)) 
        print((-b - sqrt_val)/(2 * a)) 
      
    elif dis == 0: 
        print(-b / (2 * a)) 
      
    else:
        print(- b / (2 * a), " + i", sqrt_val) 
        print(- b / (2 * a), " - i", sqrt_val)
```

Why does the program ask for the input values (as it should) but does not give any output?

Comment: Enough information to reproduce a problem needs to be included _as text, in the question itself_. See the [mre] definition.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122) -- we can't test changes to code from a screenshot without retyping it ourselves; it's not searchable; it uses lots of bandwidth; problems caused by lookalike characters can't be found.

Comment: could you pleaase post the code as code , and give an input/output example.

Comment: When you put `input()` in the funciton definition, those will run without you even having to call the function; those are executed regardless, since default values are evaluated when a function is defined, not when it's called. I don't see anywhere where you're calling the function, so I'm assuming you're never actually calling it, thus leading to no print outputs while still getting the input prompts.

Comment: @RandomDavis, after trying this I recieved the following error: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-66cd85d70a1d> in <module>
----> 1 quadratic_solver()

<ipython-input-4-7ffffb7dfaba> in quadratic_solver(a, b, c)
      3 
      4 def quadratic_solver(a = input("Enter the value of a "), b = input("Enter the value of b "), c = input("Enter the value of c ")):
----> 5     dis = b * b - 4 * a * c
      6     sqrt_val = math.sqrt(abs(dis))
      7 

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Comment: @NewDev198, that's a separate problem, already asked and answered in our knowledgebase. (Exactly as the exception says, you can't treat strings as if they were numbers; if you want something to be an `int` or a `float`, you should cast it that way after `input()` returns the string you asked it to collect). Either way, reaching that new and different problem means that the problem you asked us about is fixed.

Comment: @NewDev198 see my answer for how to fix that issue.

Comment: Please don't  add comments to clarify. Code is unreadable in comments. [Edit] your question instead. See also [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put `input()` in the function definition, those will run without you even having to call the function; those are executed regardless, since default values are evaluated when a function is defined, not when it's called. I don't see anywhere where you're calling the function, so I'm assuming you're never actually calling it, thus leading to no print outputs while still getting the input prompts.

To fix the issues, you need to call the function, as well as put the inputs inside of it.

In addition, your `a` `b` and `c` values are being read as strings, but never converted to numbers, which will lead to an error about this if you don't convert them first, so I put in a conversion to `float` in order to make it work.

```
import math

def quadratic_solver(a=None, b=None, c=None):
    if a is None:
        a = float(input("Enter the value of a "))
    if b is None:
        b = float(input("Enter the value of b "))
    if c is None:
        c = float(input("Enter the value of c "))
    dis = b * b - 4 * a * c 
    sqrt_val = math.sqrt(abs(dis)) 
   
    if dis > 0: 
        print((-b + sqrt_val)/(2 * a)) 
        print((-b - sqrt_val)/(2 * a)) 
      
    elif dis == 0: 
        print(-b / (2 * a)) 
      
    else:
        print(- b / (2 * a), " + i", sqrt_val) 
        print(- b / (2 * a), " - i", sqrt_val)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    quadratic_solver()
```

Comment: You should cast `a`, `b` and `c` to `float`

Comment: @not_speshal yeah I realized this the moment I posted my answer, I updated it just now